# python 3.65 insert query throws operational error

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I'm having issues with my insert query. I keep getting the error

Have tried several things as suggested on Google but nothing works.

My data values are populated in a list throughout my script and is the only way I can plug the values into my query.

The fields numbers and values align; I've tried all strings; I've tried using (sql_formatted,); and lastly [sql_formatted]

If I manually submit the query as one big long string in sqlite browser, it works. It's just this poncy sqlite3 library forcing me to use the (?,?,?....)format that's causing me grief.

For simplicity, I've completely broken it down:

```
sql_formatted = []
sql_formatted.append("2018-06-26")
sql_formatted.append("my test")
sql_formatted.append("1.0")
sql_formatted.append("runperiod")
sql_formatted.append("Transaction 1")
sql_formatted.append(1.776)
sql_formatted.append(8.803)
sql_formatted.append(15.161)
sql_formatted.append(4.138)
sql_formatted.append(13.999)
sql_formatted.append(0)
sql_formatted.append(0)
sql_formatted.append(0)
sql_formatted.append(0)
sql_formatted.append(0)
sql_formatted.append(0)
sql_formatted.append(0)
sql_formatted.append(0)
sql_formatted.append(0)
sql_formatted.append(0)
sql_formatted.append(0)
sql_formatted.append(0)
sql_formatted.append(0)
sql_formatted.append(0)
sql_formatted.append(0)
sql_formatted.append(0)
sql_formatted.append(0)
sql_formatted.append(0)
sql_formatted.append(15.161)
sql_formatted.append(23)
sql_formatted.append(0)
sql_formatted.append(0)
sql_formatted.append('N')

try:

cur.execute("insert into lr_rundata (current_date, test_name, app_version, test_run_period, transaction_name, '\
'sla_status, minimum, average, maximum, std_deviation, percentile80, percentile81, percentile82, percentile83, percentile84, '\
'percentile85, percentile86, percentile87, percentile88, percentile89, percentile90, percentile91, percentile92, percentile93,'\
'percentile94, percentile95, percentile96, percentile97, percentile98, percentile99, pass, fail, stop, deleted) values '\
'(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", (sql_formatted,))
```

Any suggestions would be more than welcome!!

Kind regards

Table script:

```
cur.executescript('''CREATE TABLE lr_rundata (
id      integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT,
current_date   DATETIME NOT NULL,
test_name   TEXT NOT NULL,
app_version   TEXT NOT NULL,
test_run_period   TEXT NOT NULL,
transaction_name   TEXT NOT NULL,
sla_status   INTEGER NOT NULL,
minimum   REAL NOT NULL,
average   REAL NOT NULL,
maximum   REAL NOT NULL,
std_deviation   REAL NOT NULL,
percentile80   REAL NOT NULL,
percentile81   REAL NOT NULL,
percentile82   REAL NOT NULL,
percentile83   REAL NOT NULL,
percentile84   REAL NOT NULL,
percentile85   REAL NOT NULL,
percentile86   REAL NOT NULL,
percentile87   REAL NOT NULL,
percentile88   REAL NOT NULL,
percentile89   REAL NOT NULL,
percentile90   REAL NOT NULL,
percentile91   REAL NOT NULL,
percentile92   REAL NOT NULL,
percentile93   REAL NOT NULL,
percentile94   REAL NOT NULL,
percentile95   REAL NOT NULL,
percentile96   REAL NOT NULL,
percentile97   REAL NOT NULL,
percentile98   REAL NOT NULL,
percentile99   REAL NOT NULL,
pass   INTEGER NOT NULL,
fail   INTEGER NOT NULL,
stop   INTEGER NOT NULL,
deleted        TEXT NOT NULL)''')
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Hmm, it removed my error but the one I'm getting is: [[[<class 'sqlite3.OperationalError'>]]]]

Comment: The quotes doesnot look good. You start with " and use ' in between.

Comment: I agree.  That was a suggestion I had tried.  If I remove those single quotes, it comes back with <class 'sqlite3.ProgrammingError'>.

Comment: Quotes need to be consistent. Please try the code in the answer. Does that work? If 'no', what error do you get?

Comment: Can't see my reply so sorry if this is on twice.  If I use your example again with the added correct column, It says 'Programming error' again.  If I use double quotes before "insert" and after "?)", it's back to operational error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have appended values to `sql_formatted` 33 times but you are inserting into 34 columns. Another issue is with the quotes. They are not consistent. You used double-quotes and single-quotes interchangeably. Also, since you are using the array, you don't need the tuple syntax. Refer to the code below...

I can't test it. Let me know the result:

```
cur.execute('insert into lr_rundata (current_date, test_name, app_version, test_run_period, transaction_name, '\
'sla_status, minimum, average, maximum, std_deviation, percentile80, percentile81, percentile82, percentile83, percentile84, '\
'percentile85, percentile86, percentile87, percentile88, percentile89, percentile90, percentile91, percentile92, percentile93,'\
'percentile94, percentile95, percentile96, percentile97, percentile98, percentile99, pass, fail, stop, deleted) values '\
'(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', sql_formatted)
```

Comment: Hi.  Now comes back with <class 'sqlite3.ProgrammingError'>

Comment: won't let me paste table def :(  Too long.

Comment: You have 34 columns but you appended 33 values. Correct that with the code I posted and let me know

Comment: Thanks mate.  Well spotted!!  I've added another column but still says programming error.  If I change to use double quotes before "insert" and after "?), it goes back to operational error lol  :(

Comment: Don't use the quotes the way you were using. That is wrong. Check the last line:
    '(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', sql_formatted)

Comment: OH MY!!!  You my friend, are a legend!!  Right, that works and I can't thank you enough.  So there were two things.  Using all single quotes, and using sql_formatted rather than (sql_formatted,).  Thanks again!!!!

Comment: I've up voted but not marking answer as correct.  Anyhow, thanks buddy!

Comment: @Tim Please mark this as answered. Read the answer, I've edited it to reflect the correct solution.